# Replit Python Error "Package Operation Failed"

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, replit, replit-database

I installed pysqlite but this error is shown. I also cant delete packages.
Even if I use a different package/no packages, this error will be shown.
[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42acL.png)

Comment: Error msg or screen shot is missing

Comment: uploading it right away!